# Trying to fetch a specific record in JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to fetch just one record from my JSON file, the JSON file is in the public folder
I set up a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/live/7gu09fv

What is happening now is that it just returns the first record from the JSON and isn't matching the id to pageId

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";



function FetchContent( { pageId } ) {
    
const [page, setPage] = useState([]); 

     useEffect(() => {
      fetch("pages.json" ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json =>{
             setPage(json)
      
                    }
              )
         }, []);
    
    const found = page.find(id => id = { pageId });
    
    if (!found) return <div />;
    return (
        <>
        
            <h1 key={found.id}>{found.title.rendered}: {found.id} : {pageId}</h1>
        

        </>
    );
}


function Page() {
  const { state:  { pageId }  } = useLocation();
  

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      
      <FetchContent  pageId={pageId} />
      
     </div>
  );
}
 
export default Page;
```

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function FetchContent({ pageId }) {
const [foundItem, setFoundItem] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("pages.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const found = json.find(({id}) => (id === pageId));
        setFoundItem(found);
      });
  }, [pageId]);

  if (!foundItem) return <div />;
  return (
    <>
      <h1 key={foundItem.id}>
        {foundItem.title && foundItem.title.rendered ? foundItem.title.rendered: ''}: {foundItem.id} : {pageId}
      </h1>
    </>
  );
}

function Page() {
const location = useLocation();
const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(null);
useEffect(()=> {
  if(location.state){
    setPageId(parseInt(location.state.pageId, 10));
  }
}, [location]);
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <FetchContent pageId={pageId} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: DarthJS, im not finding any of these to be working

Comment: const found = page.find(({id}) => id === pageId );

have you tried this one?

Comment: that gives me TypeError: found is undefined

Comment: it seems your response object is json.items , also your id is ID

Comment: const found = myrt.find(({ID}) => ID === pageId );

Comment: this is a part thta confuses me, I am using Wordpress JSON.. the menu JSON uses ID as the menu item but object_id as the page.. the pages JSON uses id as  the page id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225689/discussion-between-darthjs-and-justin-blayney).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const found = page.find(obj => obj.id ===  pageId);
```

Comment: Hello, that gives me no results at all

Comment: Your sandbox is different than what you are sharing on the question, can you get them aligned so it will be easy to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi Shimi, I just put it up, what isnt aligned?

Comment: oh, wait, other people are working on it and have changed things it looks like

Comment: The code on the sandbox doesn't have the `found` set up or the `found` variable mentioned at all. So I had to guess.

Comment: Your codesandbox could only be changed by you, others will need to fork it to make actual changes and that will change for them the url.